# Ideal in polynomial ring with three variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

Let $k$ be a field and $I = (y-x^2, z-x^3)$ the ideal of $k[x,y,z]$.

1. I want to find polynomials $P,Q \in k[x,y,z]$ such that $y^3-z^2 = P(x,y,z)(y-x^2) + Q(x,y,z)(z-x^3)$.

I know that such polynomials exist : in the quotient ring $k[x,y,z]/I$, the images of $x,y,z$ satisfy $\bar y^3 = \bar x^6 = \bar z^2$, i.e. $y^3-z^2 \in I$. But how to find the polynomials explicitly?

2. I want to compute $J = I \cap k[y,z]$.

I guess that the answer is $(y^3-z^2)$, as an ideal of $k[y,z]$, but I'm not sure how to prove it completely.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you choose the lexicographic order with $y>z>x$, you already have a Groebner basis, i.e. the division algorithm will yield $P$ and $Q$.

2)  Clearly $J := I \cap k[y,z] \supset (y^2-z^3)$ and $J$ is a prime ideal because $I$ is. Note that $(y^2-z^3)$ has height one, i.e. to show equality we only have to show that $J$ is not maximal. We have a ring extension $$k[y,z]/J \hookrightarrow k[x,y,z]/I=k[x],$$
which is integral, because $x$ satisfies a monic equation (for instance $x^2=y$). Thus $k[y,z]/J$ is not a field, i.e. $J$ is not maximal.

Answer (score 1):

Doing *multivariate division* of $y^3-z^2$ by $y-x^2$ and $z-x^3$ with respect to the monomial ordering $y\succ z\succ x$ we obtain
$$
(y^2+x^2y+x^4)(y-x^2)+(-z-x^3)(z-x^3)=y^3-z^2.
$$
Indeed, $\{y-x^2,z-x^3\}$ is a Groebner basis of $I$.